# Get value of dice

Tags: java, android

I want make a Dice game, i have use a github project (https://github.com/dylanmtaylor/Simple-Dice).

The MainActivity is available here : https://github.com/dylanmtaylor/Simple-Dice/blob/master/src/com/dylantaylor/simpledice/RollDice.java

I want to get the value of the dice

**Exemple :**
If the first dice is 1 and the second is 6 we have a total of 7 i want make an action.

I have make a button who change a textview, this button try to get the number of the dices.

```
TextView hwTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
                hwTextView.setText(String.valueOf(diceSum));
```

I have try to get the value "`diceSum`", "`diceImages`", "`dice`", "`dice[roll[0]`", "`dice[roll[1]`" but that didn't show a number.

How can i do try to get the value of the dice ?

My MainActivity

```
public class dices extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    private final int rollAnimations = 50;
    private final int delayTime = 15;
    private Resources res;
    private final int[] diceImages = new int[] { R.drawable.d1, R.drawable.d2, R.drawable.d3, R.drawable.d4, R.drawable.d5, R.drawable.d6 };
    private Drawable dice[] = new Drawable[6];
    private final Random randomGen = new Random();
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int diceSum;
    private int roll[] = new int[] { 6, 6 };
    private ImageView die1;
    private ImageView die2;
    private LinearLayout diceContainer;
    private SensorManager sensorMgr;
    private Handler animationHandler;
    private long lastUpdate = -1;
    private float x, y, z;
    private float last_x, last_y, last_z;
    private boolean paused = false;
    private static final int UPDATE_DELAY = 50;
    private static final int SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 800;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        paused = false;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dixit);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#2c3e50"));
        }
        View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_roll);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rollDice();
                TextView hwTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
                hwTextView.setText(String.valueOf(diceSum));
            }
        });


        res = getResources();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            dice[i] = res.getDrawable(diceImages[i]);
        }

        die1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.die1);
        die2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.die2);
        animationHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                die1.setImageDrawable(dice[roll[0]]);
                die2.setImageDrawable(dice[roll[1]]);
            }
        };


    }


    private void rollDice() {
        if (paused) return;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < rollAnimations; i++) {
                    doRoll();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.roll);
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.start();
    }

    private void doRoll() { // only does a single roll
        roll[0] = randomGen.nextInt(6);
        roll[1] = randomGen.nextInt(6);
        diceSum = roll[0] + roll[1] + 2; // 2 is added because the values of the rolls start with 0 not 1
        synchronized (getLayoutInflater()) {
            animationHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
        try { // delay to alloy for smooth animation
            Thread.sleep(delayTime);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        paused = false;
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        paused = true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Nobody know how to do this ? :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand why your code didn't work. I myself making a very small games based on "[Scarne's dice game(pig)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_(dice_game))" and myself facing the challenge of retrieving the value of dice rolled. Mind, I am just using one die. This is what I did:

```
int userScore;
private int[] diceArray = {R.drawable.d1, R.drawable.d2, R.drawable.d3,
        R.drawable.d4,R.drawable.d5,R.drawable.d6};

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void onRollBtnClicked() {
    ImageView diceFace = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.diceFaceImageView);
    userScore = randomIntegerGenerator(1,6); // this is what you need
    diceFace.setImageResource(diceArray[userScore]);

}

// function to return random integer from min to max
public int randomIntegerGenerator(int min, int max) {
     return random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}
```

I am storing my rolled die value in **userScore**. You can use the similar approach.